# Create a flow chart with node inside a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, flow-charts

I need to create a flow chart similar to the image shown below.

I cannot add node inside the node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[papersize={14cm,14cm}]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.arrows, arrows, positioning,}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{>=stealth',
punktchain/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, 
% fill=black!10,
draw=black, very thick,
inner sep=2pt, text width=3.1cm, minimum height=3em, 
text centered, on chain},
connector/.style = {->,very thick},
element/.style={tape,top color=white,
bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
minimum width=8em, draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
text width=10em,  minimum height=3.5em, 
text centered,  on chain},
every join/.style={->, very thick, shorten >=1pt},    
tuborg/.style={decorate, very thick},
tubnode/.style={midway, right=5pt},
inclass/.style = {punktchain, minimum height=6mm,
              inner sep=1mm, top color=red!15, bottom color=red!5},}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\small % \fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont
\begin{tikzpicture} [auto, >=stealth',  node distance=1cm,  start 
chain=going below]

\node[punktchain, text width = 7cm, xshift=2cm] (A2)  {Items};

\node[inclass,below=of A2.south] (A21) {item1};
\node[inclass,below=of A21.south] (A22) {item2};
\node[inclass,below=of A22.south] (A23) {ittem3};
\node[punktchain, text width = 7cm] (A3) {items};



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

in this image the item1,item2,item3 should be inside Items.
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: first draw inner nodes, then fit node around them followed with node above and below it.  since you not provide any information about node size, i cant further help you. consider above comment!

Comment: An alternative to Zarko's solution could be a `matrix` node which contains some `regular` nodes.

Comment: 'items' node size can further be increased.

Comment: Do you really need a hammersledge like TikZ for such things?

Comment: Is there any way apart from using tikz? it will be helpful for many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

in *mwe* below i consider only necessary style definitions and supoze tgant node which incapsulate three iners, has the same width as noce at top and bottom:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, chains, fit, positioning,}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{   > = stealth',
punktchain/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, very thick,
                     text width=3.1cm, minimum height=3em, inner sep=2pt,
                     align=center, on chain},
   inclass/.style = {punktchain, minimum height=6mm,
                     top color=red!15, bottom color=red!5},
              }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=8mm,
    start chain=going below,
every label/.append style={font=\footnotesize}
                       ]
\node (A2) [punktchain, text width=7cm] {Items};
%
\node (A21) [inclass, label=above left:label]   {item1};
\node (A22) [inclass]   {item2};
\node (A23) [inclass]   {ittem3};
%
\node (A3) [punktchain, text width=7cm] {items};
%
\node   [draw, very thick, rounded corners,
         inner ysep=4mm, inner xsep=0mm,
         minimum width=7cm, fit= (A21) (A22 -| A2.west)  (A22 -| A2.east) (A23)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, i need a label above item1  as items.

Comment: as label, for example `\node (A21) [inclass,label=above:label]]   {item 1};`

Comment: error,  will be changing the image if you needed i can show how i want.

Comment: ups, in example should be only one`]` not two. typo error :-(

Comment: I have added an image to the question, I need like that is that possible without the label.